# What is the best way to debug an asp page?

Tags: asp.net, debugging

I'm trying to get an ASP page to work, but it keeps blowing up. How do I get it to display "response.write" info instead of blowing up?

p.s. I noticed this as a technique and plan to give it a try.

2. On top of page ad On Error Resume Next
   After each line of code use
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   Response.Write Err.Description
   Err.Clear
   End if
   You might also Set a Debuggingvariable e.g. intDebug that you increase every
   x lines
   intDebug = intDebug + 1

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Response.Write intDebug
response.Write "
"
Response.Write Err.Description
Err.Clear
End if

Comment: Please clarify... ASP (classic) or ASP.NET.

Comment: He has said its for ASP! or am I missing something?

Comment: he tagged it as ASP.NET but it looks like ASP..

Comment: It's asp - I didn't see a tag that was asp only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this is not asp.net, but asp. I tagged it as asp.net because I didn't see a tag for asp.

Ultimate, my hacked solution was to make a huge if statement, e.g.

if 1 = 1 then
  ' continue happily displaying page
  (bunch of code until end)
else
 Response.write "messed up variable: " & messed_up_variable

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just debug ? Visual Studio's debug features are excellent.

**FOR ASP.NET :**

Just put your breakpoint and click **Debug / Attach Process**  select **aspnet_wp.exe**.

**FOR ASP :**

[Debugging Classic ASP ( VBScript ) in Visual Studio 2008](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/DebugVBScriptVS2008.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Response.Write statements you can use ASP.NET's tracing. For outputting page-level information

```
'Display an informational message
Trace.Write(category, message)

'Display a warning (shown in RED)
Trace.Warn(category, message)
```

To enable tracing output on your ASP.NET Web pages for the entire Web application, simply set enabled to true and pageOutput to true. If you are working on a live site, you can set localOnly to true, meaning that only those hitting the site through http://localhost will see the tracing information. Add these settings in the Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Set the Web.config's trace to enabled as true and requestLimit to some value greater than zero. Now, visit some ASP.NET Web pages in your Web application. Now, point your browser to http://localhost/trace.axd (or whatever the directory is for your Web application)

[Ref](https://web.archive.org/web/20210324184141/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/081501-1.shtml).

Comment: I kinda suspect that @Jack is asking about Classic ASP (notwithstanding the tags assigned to the question).

Answer (score 0):

"On Error Resume Next" --> Is obsolete.

Use Try Catch statements to cover every single piece of code that might throw an exception.

```
Try
' Statement which can cause an exception.
Catch x As Type
' Statements for handling the exception
Finally
'Any cleanup code. will run if exception occurs or not.
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the page and monitor it module by module.

Place response.write  followed by response.end.

You will know where exactly the page is breaking!

The one showed in your question is the proper way of error handling in ASP pages.

Update: Looking at the other answeres it seems the question was for ASP.net? Did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Eh... use the debugger?

> On top of page ad On Error Resume Next
>   After each line of code use If
>   Err.Number <> 0 Then Response.Write
>   Err.Description Err.Clear End if You
>   might also Set a Debuggingvariable
>   e.g. intDebug that you increase every
>   x lines intDebug = intDebug + 1

Ahrrgh. My eyes! It hurts!